# Set mysql 'bind-address' in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, master-slave

I am trying to implement mysql master/slave. For this i am using two different EC2 instances as my two servers.

Problem is when i go to /etc/mysql/my.cnf (master server) and change bind-address to SERVERIP (i am using the ec2 Public IP for this purpose), on `service mysql restart` i get error.

An alternative is setting bind-address to `0.0.0.0` but in that case my slave server is not able to connect, as on doing  `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;`

i get only:

```
Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
```

and nothing more happens.
In slave I have provided Master_Host: as my public ip of master server

Comment: I am following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

Comment: Do you have AWS security groups configured to allow necessary MySQL port access between Master and Slave?

Comment: Yeah i did so.. I can check that using telnet <ip> <port> . I also commented the bind address altogether, still no good.